# Scale image to align with hanging caption text

Tags: graphics, captions

How to automatically scale a centred image to be (at the same time to being centred) left aligned with a hanging caption?

[image]

MWE with guessed image widths:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{caption}                

\captionsetup{%
    singlelinecheck=false,
    format=hang
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{test}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Text}
\end{figure}

\setcounter{figure}{1000}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.62\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Text}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to a missunderstanding in my first answer I adapted the caption to the image. Here the image width is adapted to the caption. It works with different label formats.

For this a new caption format was written, which is a copy of the original `hang` plus a macro to calculate the `\imagewidth`. The caption must be known before the image, so the command `\captionafter` sets it into a box. The latter is then printed with `\printcaption` after the image.

Using these macros will result in this:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % just for checking centering
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{caption}                

\makeatletter
\newlength{\imagewidth}

\newcommand*{\set@imagewidth}{%
    \global\imagewidth\dimexpr\textwidth-2\caption@hangindent
}

% copoied from caption3.sty, renamed and added \set@imagewidth
\DeclareCaptionFormat{myhang}[#1#2#3\par]{%
  \caption@ifin@list\caption@lsepcrlist\caption@lsepname
    {\caption@Error{%
       The option `labelsep=\caption@lsepname' does not work\MessageBreak
       with `format=hang'}}%
    {\@hangfrom{#1#2}%
     \advance\caption@parindent\hangindent
     \advance\caption@hangindent\hangindent
     % added
     \set@imagewidth
     \caption@@par#3\par}}

% caption must be known to set \imagewidth, so store it in a box
\newbox\captionafterbox
\newcommand{\captionafter}[2][]{%
    \setbox\captionafterbox\vbox{\caption[#1]{#2}}%
}
% and print it later
\newcommand{\printcaption}{\box\captionafterbox}

\makeatother

\captionsetup{%
    singlelinecheck=false,
    format=myhang
}

% just for testing
\setcounter{totalnumber}{4}

\begin{document}

\chapter{test}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \captionafter{Text}
    \includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,height=1cm]{example-image}
    \printcaption
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \captionsetup{labelfont=bf}
    \captionafter{Text}
    \includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,height=1cm]{example-image}
    \printcaption
\end{figure}

\setcounter{figure}{1000}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \captionafter{A very long caption text, which needs more than one line. Just some more text to fill it.}
    \includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,height=1cm]{example-image}
    \printcaption
\end{figure}

\setcounter{figure}{1000000}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \captionafter{A very long caption text, which needs more than one line. Just some more text to fill it. Amd make it even longer.}
    \includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,height=1cm]{example-image}
    \printcaption
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much for this nice and clean solution!

Comment: @samcarter Thank you very much for the nice blue box below the green hook :-)

Comment: Figured your answer would look better with more colour :) Your answer help me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is a bit clumsy as it calculates the hanging indent of the caption by emulating the caption label ... this has the big drawback that it does not automatically adjust to the format of the caption, the font size and style.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{caption}                

\captionsetup{%
    singlelinecheck=false,
    format=hang
}

% calculate idention of caption
\newlength{\captionindent}
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{%
    \addtocounter{figure}{1}%
    \settowidth{\captionindent}{%
        Figure\space\thefigure:\space% 
    }%
    \addtocounter{figure}{-1}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{test}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\textwidth-2\captionindent\relax]{example-image}
    \caption{Text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you set the width of the image manually (or know it), you can use this:

**Edit:** added a command to set up caption so it ocupies the rest of the line.

**Edit 2:** added `onside` to `\captionsetup` in `\captionimagewidth`;
added a new command `\capimagewidth`, which corrects width and indent, so for wide images the label ("Figure 1.1") doesn't move into the left margin.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % just for checking centering
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{caption}                

\captionsetup{%
    singlelinecheck=false,
}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{myfigure}{\llap{#1 #2:\ }}
\captionsetup{labelformat=myfigure}

% Edit
\newlength{\capindent}
\newlength{\capwidth}
\newcommand{\captionimagewidth}[1]{%
    \capindent\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-#1/2\relax
    \capwidth\dimexpr\textwidth-\capindent
    \captionsetup{width=\capwidth,margin={\capindent,0pt},oneside}%
}

% Edit 2: added `oneside` to \captionsetup
%         correction for wide images
\newcommand{\capimagewidth}[1]{%
    \capindent\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-#1/2\relax
    % from your answer
    \addtocounter{figure}{1}%
    \settowidth{\capwidth}{%
        \figurename~\thefigure:\space% 
    }%
    \addtocounter{figure}{-1}%
    %
    \ifdim\capindent<\capwidth
        \capindent\capwidth
    \fi
    \capwidth\dimexpr\textwidth-\capindent
    \captionsetup{width=\capwidth,margin={\capindent,0pt},oneside}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{test}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}
    \captionsetup{width=0.3\textwidth}
    \caption{Text}
\end{figure}

\setcounter{figure}{1000}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
    % old
    %\captionsetup{width=0.5\textwidth}
    % Edit
    \captionimagewidth{0.5\textwidth}
    \caption{A very long caption text, which needs more than one line. Just some more text to fill it.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image}
    \capimagewidth{0.9\textwidth}
    \caption{A very long caption text, which needs more than one line. Just some more text to fill it. Amd make it even longer.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Result after edit:

[image]

But for wide images, the label moves into the margin:

[image]

With new command from second edit:

[image]

Old result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! This is an interesting solution if the caption should not occupy the whole line.

Comment: @samcarter I added a solution, wich uses the rest of the line.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort! Do you happen to see a way to move the "Figure xxxx" part to the begin of the line?

Comment: @samcarter does `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{myfigure}{\llap{\hbox to \capindent{#1~#2:\hfill}}}` do what you want? (This doesn't work with the first version.)

Comment: @samcarter And it doesn't work for wide images with the second version (`\captionimagewidth`). Where should the second line hang from, left of the image or right of the "Figure xxxx" part?

Comment: Actually I was hoping for a solution where right of "Figure xxx" and left of the image would be the same. I am perfectly content with the behaviour of a caption with hanging indent, I just want to scale the image in such a way that it aligns with the left side of caption text part. I am sorry if I could not express this clear enough in the question and I am really grateful that you take your time to have a look at this problem!

Comment: @samcarter see new answer